# Electric force between two hemispheres of different radii?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

*Two hemispherical thin shells made of insulating materials are concentrically
arranged in a free space as shown. The radii of the smaller and larger
hemispheres are ‘R’ and ‘2R’ and they carry positive charges ‘Q’ and ‘2Q’
respectively. The charges are uniformly distributed over the surfaces of the
shells.Find the force of interaction between the spheres.* **(See the image.)**[image: Figure]

Finding out the electric field due to one hemisphere and then integrating the force over elemental strips of the other seems too tedious to me. Is there better way of doing it? Like the case when the radii of the two hemispheres are same, we could find out the force using the concept of electric pressure. Not sure if we can use it here though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let the plane passing through the middle be P. Now reflect the bigger hemisphere across P. You'll notice that the smaller hemisphere is now lying inside a spherical shell hence the net force should be zero. So if the original force was F towards the right, this reflected hemisphere also applies a force F towards the left.

Now remove the first reflection and reflect the smaller hemisphere across P. This will get you a sphere inside a bigger hemisphere. Due to the first reflection, you know that the force applied on both halves of this smaller sphere by the bigger hemisphere is equal to F. Now all you need to find is what the force this smaller hemisphere applies on the bigger hemisphere(equal to 2F). For this, just use the projected area of the bigger hemisphere, all at a distance R from the smaller hemisphere, or double integrate the component of the force at every point on the hemisphere. This will give you the value of 2F, hence F.